# Android App UI layout review

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, layout, structure

Now I’m designing the UI for my first Android Application.  I just wanted to confirm if what I grasped and design choice is rightly done.

The requirement is,  I need to display a list of Images+Data on the home page, it might run into hundreds. It also contains a search header.  + category selection on thetop.

Clicking on the menu button must side the panel of links for Menu/Config.

I learnt, doing nested layouts are closer to evil in Android. So I did not put multiple one into the other.  I’ve put a simplified one.

I have shared what I’ve designed for this requirement.  Any word of concern/recommendation would be highly appreciated. 
[image]

[image]

1. SlidingPaneLayout is the root element of `MainActivity`.
2. Bottom View contains list of menus
3. Top view diplays list of Images
4. Top view has the following elements 
   Title Layout  : which is basically a `RelativeLayout`, holds Title name, burger icon and search button

**Image `ListView`** : displays list of images from local memory

**Sub Category Layout** : which is again a `RelativeLayout`. This displays the sub-category of the image displayed in the Image `listview`. This will change when user scrolls. Taping on this will display a sub-category `listview`.

**Search bar Layout** : which is a `RelativeLayout`. This has a drop down suggestion `listview`, which displays suggestions.

**Key Questions**

1. Should search be put in a separate `activity`?
2. Should search be put in a separate View/Fragment?
3. Is there any way the layouts can be reduced or replaced with better layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-2/ The ListView should be put in a separate fragment and the search should have its own also. The search view fragment should be open on press of the search icon. You have listeners for opening and collapsing the search field. The idea is to change fragment only in the host activity. Each fragment should implement its own logic.

3/ For sure don't use ListView when you are going to have hundres of items. Instead use the RecyclerView that recycles and reuses the views. ListView will be okay for the left drawer menu as its going to implement static number of elements that won't need recycling.